# Take a firebase site offline without deleting it

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a pwa in firebase and I would like to make it visible only sometimes.
How can I take a firebase site offline without deleting the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Firebase CLI reference, you can use the `hosting:disable` command to temporarily disable your site.

Link to the section in the CLI docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#hosting-commands

Comment: must I write "firebase hosting:disable"?
And to revert?

Comment: @asv Correct. Also typing `firebase hosting:enable` should revert it.

Comment: firebase hosting:enable doesn't work, but firebase deploy works.
Thank you, very helpful

Comment: You just need to publish a new deployment and it will be enabled automatically